# apktool under Ubuntu 18.04 - brut.directory.DirectoryException: file must be a directory

Tags: apktool

Ubuntu 18.04 install via Ubuntu Software apktool-new version 2.4.1

/snap/apktool-new/2/bin# ./apktool d /home/myhome/mytemp/test.apk

gives: Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.directory.DirectoryException: file must be a directory: test

Hope this helps someone:

~/mytemp$ /snap/apktool-new/2/bin/apktool d test.apk

Running terminal from your Home folder fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for the Exception issue is in the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).